# Find R and a such that $5 \sin{\theta} + 6 \cos{\theta} = R \sin(\theta + a)$

Tags: calculus

So far I have $R$ as $\sqrt{61}$. And I have $a$ as $\frac{6}{5}$ due to arctan $\frac{b}{a}$. I'm not too sure however if this is correct as it is out of $3$ marks and I don't see how it can be worth that many and I'm unsure with what is meant by $a$.

Comment: You ask for $R$ in the title, but you show that you already calculated $R$ in the text. Also, your question is not very clear.

Comment: What does the sentence "Is 6/5 a or the degree?" mean?

Comment: The question is unclear. Also $a=\tan^{-1}(\frac{6}{5})$

Answer (score 1):

$$R \cos a \sin \theta+R \sin a \cos \theta=5 \sin{\theta} + 6 \cos{\theta} $$
$$R\cos a =5;\;R\sin a =6$$
$$\tan a = \frac{6}{5}\to a=\arctan \frac{6}{5}+k\pi,\;k\in\mathbb{Z}$$
$$R^2(\cos^2 a +\sin^2 a)=61\to R =\sqrt{61}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\sin(\theta + a) = \cos a \sin\theta + \sin a \cos\theta$

Answer (score 0):

$\alpha$ is not $\frac{6}{5}$, but $\tan^{-1}(\frac{6}{5}).
$

Using the angle addition formula$$R\sin(\theta+\alpha)=R\sin(\theta)\cos(\alpha)+R\cos(\theta)\sin(\alpha)$$

and comparing sides with $R\sin(\theta+\alpha)=5\sin(\theta)+6\cos(\theta)$ you have $R\cos(\alpha)=5$ and $R\sin(\alpha)=6.$

So $R^{2}(\cos^{2}(\alpha)+\sin^{2}(\alpha))=R^{2}=5^{2}+6^{2}=61$, thus $R=\sqrt{61}$ which you've calculated correctly.

Then $\frac{R\sin(\alpha)}{R\cos(\alpha)}=\tan(\alpha)=\frac{6}{5}\implies \alpha=\tan^{-1}(\frac{6}{5})+n\pi$ for $n\in\mathbb Z$ $\space\space\space( \text{taking $n=0$ you have} \space\space \alpha=\tan^{-1}(\frac{5}{6}) \approx 50.19^{\circ})$

Answer (score 0):

Let $(a\sin \theta + b \cos \theta)$ be the expression we are concerned about. Let $a = r \cos a_0$ and $b = r \sin 
a_0$ for $r > 0$. Thus, $$ r = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}  $$ Just see this:
$$ r \sin a_0 \cos \theta + r \sin \theta \cos a_0 = r (\sin (a_0 + \theta)) = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2} \sin (a_0 + \theta)$$
Now, in our case just plug in $a = 5, b = 6$. Thus, we have that:
$$ R = \sqrt{5^2 + 6^2 } = \sqrt{61} $$
and $$ \tan a_0 = \frac{r \sin a_0}{r \cos a_0} = \frac{6}{5} \implies a = \tan^{-1} \frac{6}{5} + k \pi \quad \forall~k \in \mathbb{Z} $$